# Rss 0.92 with .NET Syndication Feed?

Tags: c#, xml, rss, feed

I'm using the following code to parse an RSS Feed. Which works fine for Rss 2.0 but falls down on Rss 0.92. Is there an easy way to do 0.92 in .NET?

I'm using .NET 3.5 for this.

```
   using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(feedUrl))
   {
      var rss = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

      items = rss.Items.Take(maxItems);

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SyndicationFeed only supports RSS 2.0 and Atom 1.0.

Your best bet would likely be to find an external library to accomplish this. http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/ is one option.

Comment: Thanks, I had begun to suspect as much.

Comment: I didn't consider this, but you could use something like Yahoo Pipes! maybe to consume that feed and spit it back out as 2.0 that you could grab. That would be then of course be reliant on an external service, so that'd be your call.

Comment: I did think of that as well actually but the problem is I'm letting an end user put in their own feed url for this component, so will need to check it essentially.